# How do disable email validation in Clearance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, clearance

I'm trying to get [Clearance](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance) to work with AWS Dynamo as the back-end store. The problem I'm having is that I can't get Clearance to **not** do the email-uniqueness validation, which it can't do because it's not able to do standard ActiveRecord uniqueness validations via a SQL query.

According to [the comments in the code](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/blob/master/lib/clearance/user.rb), I should be able to have my `User` object return `email_optional?` `true`, and that should disable the uniqueness validation on emails. So I have:

```ruby
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Dynamoid::Document
  include Clearance::User

  field :name
  field :email

  def email_optional?
    puts 'yes, email is optional'
    true
  end
end
```

But, when I try to create a user I get an error, and, more to the point, the `puts` is not executed:

```
$ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 18665
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.3)
irb(main):001:0> u = User.new(name: 'ijd', email: 'ian@fu.bar', password: 'test')
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'editor_development_users'
    from (irb):1
```

Update: the reply from @spickermann reminded me that I should have noted that I also tried without subclassing `ActiveRecord::Base` (via `ApplicationRecord`). It gives a different error:

```ruby
class User
  include Dynamoid::Document
  ....
```

```
irb(main):002:0> reload!
Reloading...
=> true
irb(main):003:0> u = User.new(name: 'ijd', email: 'ian@fu.bar', password: 'test')
ArgumentError: Unknown validator: 'UniquenessValidator'
  from app/models/user.rb:4:in `include'
  from app/models/user.rb:4:in `<class:User>'
  from app/models/user.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  from (irb):3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.new` does not trigger validations. Therefore the error cannot be connected to the validations itself.

At the moment your `User` model is kind of both: A subclass of `ActiveRecord::Base` and it behaves like a `Dynamoid::Document`.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord 
  include Dynamoid::Document

  # ...
end
```

`ActiveRecord::Base` reads the table definition from the database when an instance is initialized. This leads to your exception, because the table does not exist. Just remove the inheritance from `ApplicationRecord`.

```
class User
  include Dynamoid::Document

  # ...
end
```

The second issue when you remove the inheritance is more complex. Usually, I would suggest to just `include ActiveModel::Validations` when you want to validate models that do not inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`. But the `UniquenessValidator` isn't defined in `ActiveModel::Validations` but in `ActiveRecord::Validations` (what makes kind of sense). This makes `Clearance` incompatible with models that do not inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`.

I would probably define a dummy implementation of a `UniquenessValidator` as a work-around:

```
class User
  include Dynamoid::Document

  class UniquenessValidator
    def initialize(_options); end
    def def validate_each(_record, _attribute, _value); end
  end

  # ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I should have mentioned in the original reply that I had already tried that, but I get a different error. I've updated the post, above.

Comment: @IanDickinson TIL that the `UniquenessValidator` is not part of `ActiveModel::Validations`. I updated my answer to address the problem in your updated question.